# how to disable animator after load in from checkpoint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So for some context, I made a healthbar that loads in after 52 seconds (waits 52 seconds and then goes from 0 health to 100 health) and now I made checkpoints as well. Both work fine seperately but when I die, the healthbar animation resets and I have to wait 52 seconds for the healthbar to be visible. I tried disabling the animator when you die and respawn at a checkpoint but that doesn't work as it is overriden by my health bar script. This is my healthbar script:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class Healthbar : MonoBehaviour
 {   
 [SerializeField] private Slider slider;

 [SerializeField] private Animator anim;
 private float Waittime = 52f;

 public GameObject player;

 public void SetMaxHealth(int health)
 {
     slider.maxValue = health;
     slider.value = health;
 }
 public void SetHealth(int health)
 {
     slider.value = health;
 }

 private void Update()
 {   
     if (Waittime <= 0)
     {
         anim.enabled = false;

     }
     else
     {
         Waittime -= Time.deltaTime;
         anim.enabled = true;
     }
 }
 }
```

This is my attempt at disabling the animator after the player respawns from a checkpoint (it might help):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

 public class healthafter : MonoBehaviour
 {
 // Start is called before the first frame update
 private GameMaster GM;
 public Animator anim;

 void Start()
 {
     GM = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GM").GetComponent<GameMaster>();
     transform.position = GM.lastCheckpointPos;
     anim.enabled = false;
 }
 }
```

how do I disable the animation after the player respawns from a checkpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fxed it by referencing the waittime variable (the one that had 52 seconds and waited for the animation to load) in the checkpoint script. I then said if the tag is == player, WaiTime = 0f

Answer (score 0):

this code can be improved... but with your current scenario, you have to reset the waitTime variable too. so your start function in heathafter script should look like this.

```
public HealthBar healthbar;

 void Start()
 {
 GM = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GM").GetComponent<GameMaster>();
 transform.position = GM.lastCheckpointPos;
 anim.enabled = false;
 healthbar.ResetWaitTime(); // this will call ResetWaitTime method from your healthbar script
 }
```

Add this to your HealthBar script

```
public void ResetWaitTime(){
Waittime =52;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason, even when I change the Waittime to 0 in the "ResetWaitTime" function.

Comment: you'll have to set the WaitTime to 52, not 0